# C# の Windows Forms アプリケーションにおいて await 前後でスレッドIDを固定したい

Tags: c#

C# の Windows Forms アプリケーションにおいて、Windows Forms のイベントで async メソッドを await で待機した場合は、async メソッド内の await 前後でスレッドIDが変化しませんが、Main メソッドで async メソッドを await で待機した場合は、async メソッド内の await 前後でスレッドIDが変化します。

Main メソッドから async メソッドを実行した場合も async メソッド内の await 前後でスレッドIDを変化させないようにするにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？

尚、Main メソッド内で `task.Wait()` を使用した場合はスレッドIDが変化しないことが確認できました。
そもそも Main メソッド内で await で async メソッドを待つという考え自体が間違っているのでしょうか？
説明を頂ければありがたいです。

#### 例

##### Program.cs

```csharp
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsAppTestAwait
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static async Task Main()
        {
            // スレッドID変化あり
            await HeavyMethodAsync("Main");

            // スレッドID変化なし
            HeavyMethodAsync("Main").Wait();

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        internal static Task HeavyMethodAsync(string name)
        {
            return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{name}#{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: before");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine($"{name}#{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: after");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

##### Form1.cs

※Form1 の Load イベントで `HeavyMethodAsync` を呼んでいます

```csharp
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsAppTestAwait
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // スレッドID変化なし
            await Program.HeavyMethodAsync("Form");
        }
    }
}
```

#### 結果

```
Main#3: before
Main#4: after
Main#3: before
Main#3: after
Form#3: before
Form#3: after
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問者さんのコードで確認したわけではないですが、Main メソッドと Form1_Load メソッドでは使われる SynchronizationContext が違うのが期待（await 前後でスレッドIDを変化させない）と違った理由ではないかと思います。

アプリによりどのように違うかは以下の記事の 5, 6, 8 を見てください。

SynchronizationContext とは？
http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2020/09/30/what-is-synchronizationcontext.aspx

SynchronizationContext.Current プロパティで確認できるので自分のコードで確認してみてください。

たぶん、Main メソッドの方は上の記事で言うコンソールアプリと同じ、Form1_Load メソッドは Application.Run メソッド (現在のスレッドで標準のアプリケーション メッセージ ループの実行を開始し、指定したフォームを表示) で起動される Windows Forms ということで、 SynchronizationContext が違うと思われます。

**【追記】**

ちなみに、Main メソッドで HeavyMethodAsync("Main").Wait(); とした部分ですが、Windows Forms のような GUI アプリでそのようなことをするとデッドロックになるはずです。詳しくは以下の記事の「すべて非同期にする」のセクションを見てください。

非同期プログラミングのベスト プラクティス
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

そうならないようですので、そこはコンソールアプリと同じになっていると思います。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。SynchronizationContext が Form と Main で異なり、await 前後での挙動が異なることを把握できました。Main メソッド内での呼び出し時は 8 のコンソールアプリと同じく、null になっていることを確認しました。
「非同期プログラミングのベスト プラクティス」のサイトについては全てを把握できていませんが、仰られている通り例の `HeavyMethodAsync("Main").Wait();` ではデッドロックはしていません。もう少し勉強してみます。

Comment: 紹介した記事の 8 に、コンソールアプリでは「await が完了するとき、スレッドプールを備えた既定の SynchronizationContext を使って、スレッドプールのスレッドで async メソッドの残り処理のスケジュールが設定される。」と書きましたが、それゆえ Main メソッドのところでは表題にある「await 前後でスレッドIDを固定」ということはできない、すなわち OS 任せになる（OS がスレッドプールからスレッドを取得する）ということは理解していただけたでしょうか？

Comment: 一方、Windows Forms の方は、紹介した記事の 6 に「await で待機するとき現在の SynchronizationContext がキャプチャされ、await が完了するとキャプチャした SynchronizationContext で続きを実行する。その際に使われるスレッドは await 前後で同じ、即ち UI スレッドになる」と書いたように、普通に表題にある「await 前後でスレッドIDを固定」となるということは理解いただけたでしょうか？

Comment: その部分について理解できたと言って良いかわかりませんが、認識は出来ました。その挙動になることを受け止めました。Windows Forms での挙動は今までいくつか動かしてみて認識しておりましたが、Main メソッド（コンソールアプリ）については初めて認識しました。

Answer (score 3):

はい、 Main メソッド内で await で async メソッドを待つという考え自体が間違っています。このアプローチでは、`HeavyMethodAsync`が完了してからしか、Mainメソッドの後続行は実行されません。本当に実現したいのは、

- 重い処理（`HeavyMethodAsync`）を起動時に開始し
- 並行してGUI（`Form1`）の表示も開始したい

ではありませんか？
そうであれば行うべきは

- `HeavyMethodAsync`を別スレッドで実行し
- メインスレッドはGUI（`Form1`）の表示も開始する

必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 Main メソッド内で await で async メソッドを待つという考え自体が間違っていることについて理解しました。

元の質問と反れてしまうかもしれませんが、実は `HeavyMethodAsync` で前処理をした後に、メインスレッドを使用して別のフォームを表示したいと考えておりました。
すみません、もう少し自分の中で整理が必要かも知れません。